# RestKit: error fetching transformable attribute from a ChildContext to mainQueueMOC

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am using RestKit to fetch data from backend and persist it on CoreData.
My TableViewController's FRC is set to `[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext`

To manipulate this data, I have a view controller in which I can create or edit managedObjects.
For this, I create a `scratchMOC` in the view controller by-

```
myMOC = [[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore] 
            newChildManagedObjectContextWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType 
            tracksChanges:NO]

self.album = (Album *)[self.scratchMOC objectWithID:album.objectID];
```

Before exiting the view controller, I would like to persist it to the PSC and get the object into the `[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext`

For this, I do-

```
[self.album saveToPersistentStore:&error];
self.album = (Album *)[[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext 
                          objectWithID:self.album.objectID];
```

Now when I check the attributes of `self.album`, any attribute with type 'transformable` is nil while others are filled in.

However, instead of using `mainQueueManagedObjectContext`, if I use `persistentStoreManagedObjectContext` all attributes (including transformable ones) are correctly filled in.

This seems to be an incorrect behavior, but I am not sure why this is occurring.

Details about RestKit's managedObjectContext architecture is available here-
http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKManagedObjectStore.html

Comment: Why are you using `tracksChanges:NO` ?

Comment: @Wain I am using `trackChanges:NO` so that if there is an operation in the background that updates the objects in the persistentStore, it does not get updated in the childContext.

Comment: Have you logged the object before and after the save? Checked the status and error of the save?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by executing

```
[[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext refreshObject:self.album mergeChanges:NO];
```

after

```
self.album = (Album *)[[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext 
                      objectWithID:self.album.objectID];
```